# JavaFX - how to solve (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException) error / i get this When i add @FXML to controller class

Tags: java, javafx, controller, scenebuilder

```html
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Odimah_v10/eclipse-workspace/ADS/bin/application/Design.fxml:60

 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
 at application.Main.start(Main.java:25)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
 ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.awt.TextField field application.DesignController.txtf_adsn to javafx.scene.control.TextField
 at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Unknown Source)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.injectFields(FXMLLoader.java:1163)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$1600(FXMLLoader.java:103)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:857)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:751)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
 ... 12 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

Im designing a simple intefrace with cambobox and textfield 
i have: Main Class / Design.fxml and DesignController.fxml
when i add @FXML tag for my design components on my controller class i get java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException error

```js
public class DesignController implements Initializable   {
    
 @FXML
    private TextField g2_txtf_3;

    @FXML
    private TextField g2_txtf_4;

    @FXML
    private TextField g2_txtf_1;

    @FXML
    private TextField g2_txtf_2;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox g3_chb_1;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<?> com3_oper;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> colum_operateur;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<?> com2_conf;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox g6_chb_1;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox h_chb_ENNA;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker g2_date;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker g7_date6;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtf_autre;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker g7_date5;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox h_chb_EXPL;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<String> h_com_location;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<?> com6_it_dest;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker g7_date4;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker g7_date3;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker g7_date2;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtf_hours;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker g7_date1;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<?> g8_comb_nom;

    @FXML
    private Button bt_db_print;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<?> com7_comp;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox g5_chb_1;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<?> g8_comb_code2;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtf_adsn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> colum_date;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker h_date;

    @FXML
    private Button bt_a4_save;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox chb_autres;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<?> com4_etat;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<?> com8_lieu;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtf_minutes;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<?> com5_it_depar;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<?> com9_imm;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<?> g8_comb_code;

    @FXML
    private Button bt_a4_new;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<?> g8_comb_nom2;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> colum_inspecteur;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox g4_chb_1;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<?> com1_type_aer;

    @FXML
    private Button bt_a4_print;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<?> com10_type;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox h_chb_DACM;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> colum_nads;

    @FXML
    private Button bt_db_delete;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<?> com11_pays;

    @FXML
    private Button bt_db_edit;

    @FXML
    private TableView<?> tb_db;
  
 ObservableList<String> names = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Mary", "Bob", "sam");

 @Override
 public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) { 
  
  
  function_combo1();
  
      }

 private void function_combo1() 
 {
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  for(String content:names) {
   list.add(content);}
  
  ObservableList obList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(list);
  h_com_location.setItems(obList);
 }

 



}
```

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.Cursor?>
<?import javafx.scene.Group?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Region?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="1008.0" prefWidth="1406.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ecf0f1;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="525.0" layoutY="7.0" prefHeight="880.0" prefWidth="878.0">
         <children>
            <ScrollPane prefHeight="949.0" prefWidth="876.0" style="-fx-border-color: black;">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="1683.0" prefWidth="859.0">
                     <children>
                        <Pane layoutX="-5.0" layoutY="3.0" prefHeight="1689.0" prefWidth="851.0" style="-fx-background-color: #f7f1e3;">
                           <children>
                              <Group layoutX="23.0" layoutY="23.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <Group />
                                    <Group layoutX="269.0" />
                                    <Group layoutX="532.0">
                                       <children>
                                          <Region layoutX="-262.0" prefHeight="152.0" prefWidth="550.0" style="-fx-border-color: #000000; -fx-background-color: #f7f1e3;" />
                                          <Label layoutX="-235.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="N° ADS :">
                                             <font>
                                                <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                                             </font>
                                          </Label>
                                          <Label layoutX="-162.0" layoutY="16.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="46.0" text="ADS">
                                             <font>
                                                <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                                             </font>
                                          </Label>
                                          <TextField fx:id="txtf_adsn" layoutX="-133.0" layoutY="9.0" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="46.0" style="-fx-background-color: 000000;" text="001">
                                             <opaqueInsets>
                                                <Insets />
                                             </opaqueInsets>
                                             <font>
                                                <Font size="16.0" />
```

```html
package application;
 
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class Main extends Application {
 private FXMLLoader loader;
 
 @Override
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
  
  
  loader = new FXMLLoader();
  loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Design.fxml"));
  DesignController controller = new DesignController();
  loader.setController(controller);
  loader.load();
  Scene scene = new Scene(loader.getRoot());
  scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
  primaryStage.setScene(scene);
  primaryStage.setResizable(false);
  primaryStage.setTitle("JAVA FX");
  primaryStage.show();
  
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  launch(args);
 }
}
```

JavaFX - how to solve (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException) error / i get this When i add @FXML to controller class

Comment: First, read [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788). Second, look at the message in the last `Caused by:`. Third, look at your imports in the `DesignController` class and fix them (hint: AWT != JavaFX).